# Error:(40, 20) TS2339:Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string | Book | Book[]'. Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am implementing @ngrx in angular2 app and when try to compile the typescript project I am getting below error.

`Error:(40, 20) TS2339:Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string | Book | Book[]'.   Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'.`

I think the error is related to union type of typescript which is used in the ngrx example app

[link to the app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app)

Comment: Rather than posting the link to your repo, post the relevant code..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Changing the compiler target to "es6" in tsconfig.js,  solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to tell without seeing your code and getting more details, but it looks like you are trying to do a map on the object returned by the Observable instead of mapping the actual Observable.